# Configure electron-builder to run powershell script

Tags: javascript, windows-installer, electron, electron-builder

I have an installation file created by electron-builder and faced issue that can't find a way how to run powershell script after installation.

The idea is to make some changes in windows registry and set permission for application folder.

As far as I understand it should be configured in `build` section in `package.json`. In api I found that it is exist `afterPack` method, but I can't figure it out how to execute powershell file through it.

Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the powershell tag from your question, even though your question _involves_ powershell it's not a question _about_ powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create an `afterPack.js` file, containing this code:

```
exports.default = async function () {
    const { exec } = require('child_process');
    const bat = exec('powershell "& ""path/to/powershell/file.ps1"""');
}
```

Edit the path to the .ps1 file accordingly. You may need to add a '.\' to the start of the path. The console readout will tell you if you do.

Next, edit your package.json file to include an `afterPack` parameter in your build settings, like so:

[image]

Now when you run your build script, it will run your `.ps1` file.

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is it.

Comment: Is there any way to find out where application was installed to apply permissions to this folder through powershell ?

Comment: I'm sure there is. I would look at [AfterPackContext](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#afterpackcontext) and/or [BuildResult](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#buildresult) , particularly the `outDir` property. How you actually use these interfaces is beyond me. Post another question and I'm sure someone will be able to help.